# An error occurred while installing the project

Tags: magento2, module, installation, php-7, server-setup

An error occurred while installing the project. I install using composer. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a Magento installation to work the machine is installed on has to meet certain requirements.

Certain libraries are part of that requirements. Libraries like `curl` or `ext-curl` that are missing on the machine you are trying to install Magento on as explicitly mentioned in the errors provided via print-screen.

A full list of the requirements needed by Magento can be found in the official docs 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Also installing any third party module/extension might come with requirements of their own.

Steps to fix your problem:

1. Install all extensions required by Magento and/or any third party modules as specified in the documentation.
2. When errors arise read information provided. In most cases is useful

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands as **sudo / root** user to install all [Magento Linux Server requirements](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common python-software-properties
apt-get update
apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libedit-dev \
    libedit2 \
    libxslt1-dev \
    apt-utils \
    mysql-client \
    git \
    vim \
    wget \
    curl \
    lynx \
    psmisc \
    unzip
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some default php extensions are needed to be enabled to get the **Magento** to work into your system

Here is the list of the extensions

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll 
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
```

Just open the `php.ini` file in your system & remove the semicolon(;) before the above listed extensions stop your `Apache server`  restart it again & try to run the magento

if still facing some issue feel free to comment